# Syntax for passing data into an Angular Directive

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I've got a directive in an Angular3 Dart project:

```
@Directive(
    selector: "[sample]",
    inputs: const ["text1", "text2"]
)
class SampleDirective implements AfterContentInit {

    ... more code ...

    @Input("text1") String text1 = "Some Text 1";
    @Input("text2") String text2 = "Some Text 2";

}
```

Now when I'm using this directive:

```
<a-component *sample></a-component>
```

How do I pass in the `text1` and `text2` fields?

The cheatsheat mentions this example: `<p *myUnless="myExpression">...</p>`, but doesn't state what the `myExpression` part should look like.

These are the ones I've already tried, but none of them compiles.

```
<a-component *sample="text1:'TESTING' "></a-component>
<a-component *sample="text1='TESTING' "></a-component>
<a-component *sample="{text1:'TESTING'}"></a-component>
<a-component *sample="{text1='TESTING'}"></a-component>
```

Any idea how these expressions should be structured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Input("sampleText1") String text1 = "Some Text 1";
```

or

```
@Input() String sampleText1 = "Some Text 1";
```

with

```
<a-component *sample="text1:'TESTING' "></a-component>
```

or

```
<template sample [sampleText1]="'TESTING'">
  <a-component></a-component>
</template>
```

**update**

There needs to be an `@Input()` that matches the selector of the directive

```
@Input() 
String sample;
```

and a value needs to be passed

```
<a-component *sample="'someValueForSample' text1:'TESTING' "></a-component>
```

then after that value assignments for other inputs can be added.

Comment: `<sample-form-3 *sample="text1:'TESTING' "></sample-form-3>` gives me `ParseErrorLevel.FATAL: Parser Error: Unexpected token :, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 13 in [sample text1:'TESTING' ] `

Comment: I'm quite sure I tested it. I'll have another look tomorrow.

Comment: I realized I was missing such a variable.
Also, any secondary inputs needs to start with the same part as the directive, so text1:TESTING only sets if I have an input called sampleText1, otherwise it simply throws a FATAL exception. Very fincky to use.